# How Can I Get URL Column to Open in New Window in SharePoint 2016

Tags: custom-list

I added the Site Column "URL" to my custom list. Now I need to have the link open in a new window.  This is SharePoint 2016 so I can no longer use a calculated column to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON formatting for the column with `target` as `_blank` it will open.
Try this:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "=@currentField"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you also want to keep the URL Tag or name that you give as "Alternative Text", I modified the code slightly:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField.desc",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "=@currentField"
   }
}
```